# Debugging Haxe (ActionScript 3)

Tags: haxe

Are there any reliable debuggers for Haxe out there, in an ActionScript 3 context, and do they support breakpoints, conditional breakpoints, watches, locals and stacks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FlashDevelop has a pretty good debugger now and it supports haxe AS3.

For haxe it must be enabled per project - see 'Enable Debugger' in the Project's Compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe you can add -D fdb to the hxml build arguments and then in FlashDevelop I think you will be able to use breakpoints and such.

Never tried it myself though as I don't run FlashDevelop on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

When you run with `Flow` you just add the `--debug` flag like this:

```
haxelib run flow run --debug
```